# My thread wont run? Java

Tags: java, multithreading

So basically my thread wont, execute..

```
import java.lang.*;

class Practice extends Thread {
    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println("Executed by thread");
    }
}

class Thread_Demo {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Practice p = new Practice();
        Thread th = new Thread(p,"My Thread");
        th.start();
        p.start();
    }
}
```

Please help me with this, The thread won't execute. Even got a screenshot of this http://prntscr.com/33b20m

Comment: FYI you never need to `import java.lang.*` because it's always imported automatically.

Comment: You are using 2 threads and both threads will run

Comment: Your screenshot clearly shows you have not saved your code.Save it and then clean build it in order to make it run

Comment: @AbhinavKumar Good catch noticing that little star

Comment: @Kon Hehehe ,should i post this as an answer :P

Comment: @AbhinavKumar It's technically correct so I would say yes.

Comment: @AbhinavKumar You don't require to save the file in Eclipse to run it, Nevertheless Thank you sorted it!

Answer (score 3):

It runs. It prints "Executed by thread" twice.

Did you right click the Thread_Demo class and select "run"?

Comment: He hasnt saved the code.Just check his screenshot of eclipse

Comment: Doesn't eclipse usually auto-prompt you to save your code when you select to run it? I wouldn't think that would be the issue. Although I always set it up to auto save, so I may not be remembering correctly.

Comment: it does but if he is running his compiled code through command prompt or any other way,it wont!!!

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't execute because it is not saved in Eclipse. If you run it after saving, you'll find that it prints the result twice. For this to work (print only once), use this

```
Practice p = new Practice();
p.start();
```

---

**TIPS:**
Don't make your `Parctice` class extend `Thread` (there's a reason for this which I'll add later). Implement `Runnable` instead:

```
class Practice implements Runnable {
    Thread t;
    boolean stopReq;
    public Practice() {
        //start(); - You may automatically start it.
    }
    public void start() {
        stopReq = false;
        t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }
    public void stop() {
        stopReq = true;
        t = null;;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10 && !stopReq; i++) {
            System.out.println("Executed by thread");
        }
    }
}

class Thread_Demo {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Practice p = new Practice();
        p.start();
    }
}
```

---

The reason why I recommend you *not to extend `Thread`* because you need to extend something only if you add something (some extra functionality) to it. Moreover, you can extend ***only one*** class, while you can ***implement*** several interfaces.

Comment: What's the reason? I have foolishly believed for the last 18 years that it's perfectly fine to extend Thread rather than implement Runnable if you want to run some code in a Thread. (I'm not talking about thread pools, executors, futures, etc. because the OP isn't either)

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt See the edit. Please understand the point, this exact reason is use by most developers.

Comment: @Downvoter (<-Dont know if this works), but please explain the reason for the downvote.

Comment: I agree that there are particular situations in which you don't want to extend Thread, and you mentioned some of them above. But I don't think that extending Thread was the reason that the OP's example didn't work.

Comment: I didn't downvote btw, although I don't think you're answering the question.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt How about now?

Comment: You must mean "while you can implement several ***interfaces***."